# "GPWRT_34065 [ERROR] Gpload error: unexpected error -- backtrace written to log file"

Tags: mapping, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, backtrace

I've recently updated a mapping in Informatica designer which used to work without any problem, I added two columns in the target table, i did some calculation in an expression, then link two-port to the newly created columns in the target table, but when I started the session, after few time I got the error below :

```html
*WRITER_1_*_1 GPWRT_34065  [ERROR] Gpload error: unexpected error -- backtrace written to log file*
```

note: the data in the new columns don't contain any special characters or delimiter.

Comment: can you encapsulate your error in a code snippet?

Comment: done, Thanks  @Heimdalssidstevogter  for the remark

Comment: can you pls check the data type of the columns in expression, informatica target definition, and in database?

Comment: problem solved, I recreated the target table, (with the same DDL), it's bizarre, but it works for me. I still don't understand why I got the error message mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, I have recreated the target table,there was a missing field in the first table. so after adding it, the workflow ran successfully